# Взаимодействие контейнеров между собой в docker swarm

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, docker-swarm, docker-machine

Есть рой с виртуальными нодами. С помощью Docker stack deploy развертывается кластер Consul

```
version: '3.6'

x-consul: &consul
  image: consul:latest
  volumes:
    - consul:/consul

volumes:
  consul:

services:
  client:
    <<: *consul
    command: "agent -retry-join server-bootstrap -client 0.0.0.0 -bind '{{ GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\" }}'"
    depends_on:
     - server-bootstrap
    deploy:
      replicas: 2

  server:
    <<: *consul
    ports:
     - "8500:8500"
    depends_on:
    - server-bootstrap
    command: "agent -server -retry-join server-bootstrap -client 0.0.0.0 -bind '{{ GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\" }}' -ui"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    placement:
      constraints: [node.role == manager]

   server-bootstrap:
     image: consul
     command: "agent -server -bootstrap-expect 3 -client 0.0.0.0 -bind '{{ GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\" }}'"
     deploy:
       placement:
         constraints: [node.role == manager]
```

А так же развертываю(в этом же файле, т.е. у них одна сеть) контейнер с своим образом spring на одном из воркеров. Вопрос, по какому адресу должен подключаться spring, ибо localhost:8500 не доступен из контейнера

Answer (score 0):

имя сервиса по дефолту является хостом сервиса в докерсварме. Хост можно переопределись параметром host